# Dropdown on table that allows item to only be selected once per row

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and I am have successfully created a table of records from my data source.  I need to add a dropdown with two choices "Primary" and "Secondary" to each row in the table.  I need to remove the selected option from the other items in the table.  For example if the first row in the table has selected "Primary" I need to not allow it to be selected again for the other rows.  I have an unknown number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this feature, your individual rows need to have access to the other rows to check for values that are in use. Before we implement this feature, let's code a naive example first, so we know what we're working with.

### Starting point

If you run the snippet below, you'll see the general UI *without* the feature you describe.

<sub>When asking a question on Stackoverflow, you usually include these kinds of examples yourself, so people have a great starting point to help you solve your problems! But since you're a new contributor, this one is on me .</sub>

```js
function Row(id) {
  this.name = id;
  this.selectedSource = ko.observable(null);
  this.sourceOptions = [ "Primary", "Secondary" ]
};


function App() {
  this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  let lastRowId = 0;
  this.addRow = () => {
    this.rows.push(
      new Row(lastRowId++)
    );
  }
};

const app = new App();
ko.applyBindings(app);

app.addRow();
app.addRow();
app.addRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
      <select data-bind="value: selectedSource,
                         options: sourceOptions,
                         enable: sourceOptions.length,
                         optionsCaption: 'select source'">
                         </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addRow">add row</button>
```

### Adding the new feature

The example above assumes a static list of `sourceOptions`. In reality however, it's a computed list:

- Start with *all* possible values
- Remove all values that are selected by *other* rows

To implement this feature, we'll first need access to the other rows:

```
/* Row accepts a reference to its siblings (including itself) */
function Row(is, allRows) { /* ... */}

/* App passes a reference to all rows when constructing new ones */
new Row(0, this.rows);
```

Now that we've got access to the other rows, we can check their selections and remove them from the list of available options:

```
// Remove this row from the list
const otherRows = ko.pureComputed(() =>  
  allRows().filter(row => row !== this)
);

// Create a Set of all selections
const otherSelections = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  new Set(otherRows().map(row => row.selectedSource()))
);

// Take the Base list and remove any element that is in otherSelections
this.sourceOptions = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  [ "Primary", "Secondary" ]
    .filter(s => !otherSelections().has(s))    
);
```

Check out the runnable snippet below to see it in action. I've also added an `enable` binding to indicate when no options are left to select!

Leave a comment if things are still unclear. I'm happy to help.

```js
function Row(id, allRows) {
  this.name = id;
  this.selectedSource = ko.observable(null);
  
  const otherRows = ko.pureComputed(() => 
    allRows().filter(row => row !== this)
  );
  
  const otherSelections = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    new Set(otherRows().map(row => row.selectedSource()))
  );
  
  this.sourceOptions = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    [ "Primary", "Secondary" ]
      .filter(s => !otherSelections().has(s))    
  );
};


function App() {
  this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  let lastRowId = 0;
  this.addRow = () => {
    this.rows.push(
      new Row(lastRowId++, this.rows)
    );
  }
};

const app = new App();
ko.applyBindings(app);

app.addRow();
app.addRow();
app.addRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
      <select data-bind="value: selectedSource,
                         options: sourceOptions,
                         enable: sourceOptions().length,
                         optionsCaption: 'select source'">
                         </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addRow">add row</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was working on an example to post but you were too fast.  :-)    I had to scrub the data I was using.  I was able to incorporate your solution into my app.  If I were to have more kids  "user3297291" would be a funny name for them  but these days I have heard some that make less sense.  ;-)